# How do I access a "getter" of a Java method from a scala method?

Tags: java, scala, getter-setter

I have a Java method that looks something like this:

```
public class JavaClass{

private static ArrayList<String> stringModel= new ArrayList<String>();

public JavaClass (String name) {
-----------------------------
-----------------------------
     /*Do required operations*/
-----------------------------
-----------------------------

}

public static ArrayList<String> getStringModel() {
    return autosarModel;
}
public static void setStringModel(ArrayList<String> stringModel) {
    JavaClass.stringModel = stringModel;
}
```

I am trying to access the getStringModel from my scala classthat looks something like this:

```
 val sm = new JavaClass("Folder1")
 val x = sm.getStringModel
```

I can seem to use the setStringModel from this scala class, but for some reason I get an error saying:

> "value getStringModel" not found.

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is [`static`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html), meaning it's defined on the *class* rather than an *instance* of the class.

You need:

```
val model = JavaClass.getStringModel("Folder1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just change the access of the static element as public and just use it?

```
 object howToGetStaticValue {
      def main(arg:Array[String]): Unit ={
         println(JavaClass.stringModel)

     }
  }
```